# How to link classes and menus

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am really struggling with linking menus together.  The app I want to create os a collection of menus that leads to url links to various sites I plan to open within the application.  I have created a list activity menu with 8 options and I have eight classes with further options.  My problem is how to link the menus together.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    // Create an array of Strings, that will be put to our ListActivity
    String[] names = new String[] { "P", "Ch", "Le", "Le", "B", "Sk", "Awa", "Tra"};
    // Create an ArrayAdapter, that will actually make the Strings above
    // appear in the ListView
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, names));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    // Get the item that was clicked
    Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    String keyword = o.toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, "You selected: " + keyword, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();


        }
    }
```

At the moment all this does is print the selection using the toast method but how do I get it  to switch to the p.java class when I have selected it.  In basic I would take the names variable and say if names = p goto p.java, I have googled and although I get part of the answer I cannot figure out how to implement it.

Many Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that rather than a class, what you want is an instance of the class in question.  One way to do that would be with a Map:

```
Map<String, Runner> runners = new HashMap<String, Runner>();
runners.put("P", new P());
runners.put("Ch", new Ch());
// etc.
```

(where Runner is an interface that all your classes implement).  Then, inside your `onListItemClick()` method, where you have the toast:

```
runners.get(keyword).run();
```

(where run() is the method you want to launch).

**Update** (to address your comment)

It's hard to say exactly where to place which bits of code, but based on your question:

You could make runners a field in your Activity, and initialize it in your same onCreate function.  So that part's handled.

The Runner interface could be as simple as this (in its own file):

```
public interface Runner {
   public void run();
}
```

and each of your classes (P, Ch, Le, etc.) would have an `implements` bit in the constructor:

```
public class P implements Runner {
```

And would have to include a run() method (which could simply call whatever existing method you want called for the URL):
    public void run() {
        // do whatever you want done here
    }

Comment: Hi Carl, Thanks for your response, Sorry I am a noob and maybe I'm running before I can walk but where should I place the code, do I delete the other classes and have the other menus within the same class or where can I find an example of this so I can see how this works